# Is it OK to delete default database migrations for app using a non-default database connection?

Tags: django, database, migration

I use multiple DATABASE keys (connection names) in my settings.py, for various apps, some using mysql, some using postgresql.

I noticed that in the default database table django_migrations it also stores migrations for those apps that are NOT using the default database.
Is it OK if I delete them? Or if they are needed, what are they used for?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by deleting them other than about 200 bytes of storage?

Comment: When I change one of my non-default DATABASEs to use postgresql from mysql, the command: "python.py migrate --database=changed_database_key_name" seems 'fooled' and fails to notice that the postgresql database needs migrations run on it. I thought maybe the migrations in the default database were confusing the migrations system and causing the failure.